# Correlated subqueries: How to get the ID of the outer query?

Tags: sql, sum, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have multiple tables :

```
Person
---------------------
IDPerson, Name

StickerTransaction
---------------------
IDTransac, IDPerson, IDSomeoneElse, NbStickersReceived, NbStickersGiven

Purchase
---------------------
IDPurchase, IDPerson, NbStickersBought
```

I'm trying to get every person who never made a transaction or currently have 0 sticker. To have the number of stickers a person has, here's the formula :

```
NbStickersBought + NbStickersReceived - NbStickersGiven
```

Here's the query I've got so far. The problem I've got is that in the subsubsubqueries... I do not have access to the person's ID.

Is there a way to have access to the person's ID or is there a better way to do write this query ?

```
SELECT People.IDPerson, People.Name
FROM
(
    -- Selects people that never made a sticker transaction

    SELECT p.IDPerson, p.Name
    FROM Person p
    LEFT JOIN StickerTransaction sT
    ON p.IDPerson = sT.IDPerson
    WHERE sT.IDPerson IS NULL

    UNION

    -- Selects people that have currently 0 sticker

    SELECT p.IDPerson, p.Name
    FROM Person p
    WHERE 0 = (
                SELECT SUM(NbStickers) AS NbStickers
                FROM (

                       -- I do not have access to p.IDPerson here...

                       SELECT (sT.NbStickersReceived - sT.NbStickersGiven) AS NbStickers
                       FROM StickerTransaction sT
                       WHERE sT.IDPerson = p.IDPerson

                     UNION ALL

                       -- I do not have access to p.IDPerson here either...

                       SELECT pu.NbStickersBought AS NbStickers
                       FROM Purchase pu
                       WHERE pu.IDPerson = p.IDPerson
                     )
              )
) People
```

Comment: Which dbms product are you using? The sub-queries are supposed to have access to their outer query's p.IDPerson.

Comment: I use HFSQL, the DBMS that comes with WinDev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do a correlation into a Derived Table. But you can rewrite your query to a non-correlated subquery:

```
SELECT People.IDPerson, People.NAME
FROM
(
    -- Selects people that never made a sticker transaction

    SELECT p.IDPerson, p.NAME
    FROM Person p
    LEFT JOIN StickerTransaction sT
    ON p.IDPerson = sT.IDPerson
    WHERE sT.IDPerson IS NULL

    UNION

    -- Selects people that have currently 0 sticker

    SELECT p.IDPerson, p.NAME
    FROM Person p
    JOIN     (
                SELECT sT.IDPerson, SUM(NbStickers) AS NbStickers
                FROM (

                       SELECT (sT.NbStickersReceived - sT.NbStickersGiven) AS NbStickers
                       FROM StickerTransaction sT

                     UNION ALL

                       SELECT pu.NbStickersBought AS NbStickers
                       FROM Purchase pu
                     ) dt
                GROUP BY sT.IDPerson
                HAVING SUM(NbStickers) = 0
             ) sT
    ON sT.IDPerson = p.IDPerson

) People
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT People.IDPerson, People.Name
FROM Person 
where IDPerson not in 
   (select distinct IDPerson from StickerTransaction)
and IDPerson not in 
   (SELECT IDPerson from Purchase group by IDPerson having SUM(NbStickers) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to find those who never purchased.

Use another sub-query to find those who have same number of NbStickersReceived as NbStickersGiven.

```
SELECT p.IDPerson, p.Name
FROM Person p
where not exists (select 1 from Purchase
                  where IDPerson = p.IDPerson)
   or 0 = (select sum(NbStickersReceived) - sum(NbStickersGiven)
           from StickerTransaction
           where IDPerson = p.IDPerson)
```

Perhaps you need `COALESCE` around the 2nd sub-query, to handle persons without any StickerTransactions.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make the link in the outer statement.

```
-- Selects people that have currently 0 sticker
SELECT p.IDPerson, p.Name
 FROM Person p,
 (SELECT sT.IDPerson, SUM(NbStickers) sum_stickers
    FROM ((SELECT sT.IDPerson, (sT.NbStickersReceived - sT.NbStickersGiven) AS NbStickers
 FROM StickerTransaction sT)
UNION
(SELECT pu.IDPerson, pu.NbStickersBought AS NbStickers
  FROM PURCHASE pu
  ))
 group by sT.IDPerson
) zeroSticker
where zeroSticker.IDPerson = p.IDPerson and zeroSticker.sum_stickers = 0
```

Because there is no possibility in plain SQL to inject a parameter into a subquery.